# tex4ht and tex4ebook: problems when tikzcd is put in the inline math

Tags: tex4ht, tikz-cd, inline, tex4ebook

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts, accents}

% Include the following code before \usepackage{tikz}
\ifdefined\HCode
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\newcommand{\cat}[1]{
\StrLen{#1}[\mystrlen]
\ifnum\mystrlen=1 \mathscr{#1}
\else \mathrm{#1}
\fi}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
  
\section{Something}
\label{sec:a}

\subsection{Else}\label{sec:e}

There is a colimit
$\begin{tikzcd}[cramped]
\cat{X}_0\ar[r] & \cat{X}_1\ar[r] & \mc{X}_2\arrow[r] & \dots\ar[r] & \cat{X}.
\end{tikzcd}$

\end{document}
```

Compiled with `make4ht`, there are errors:

```
[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of testse2.html failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: ...ive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/sub) [char=1066]
```

Compiled with `tex4ebook`, the preceding error is also there. Furthermore, the hyperlinks of ToC is invalid. The `html` code for the ToC:

```html
  <div class='tableofcontents'>   <span class='sectionToc'><a href='#contents' id='QQ2-2-1'>Contents</a></span><br /><span class='sectionToc'> 1.  <a href='testse2.html#something' id='QQ2-3-2'>Something</a></span><br /><span class='subsectionToc'>   1.1.  <a href='testse2.html#else' id='QQ2-3-3'>Else</a></span><br />
  </div>
```

and the `html` code for the only section:

```html
<div class="crosslinks"><p class="noindent"></p></div>
  <h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">1. </span> <a 
 id="x3-20001"></a>Something</h3>
<!--l. 29--><p class="noindent" ><span class="subsectionHead"><span class="titlemark">1.1. </span> <a 
 id="x3-30001.1"></a><span 
class="ecbx-1000">Else.</span></span>
  There is a colimit <img 
src="test-29e6ea9180db52c3bc6c04bd72320463.svg" alt=" <sub>0</sub>       <sub>1</sub>      <sub>2</sub>     …        ."  />
</p>   

                                                                     

                                                                     
  <!--l. 36--><div class="crosslinks"><p class="noindent"></p></div>
```

I wonder the reason and a proper workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the DOM error because of this HTML code:

```
 <img 
src="sample0x.svg" alt=" <sub>0</sub>       <sub>1</sub>      <sub>2</sub>     …        ."  />
```

As you can see, the `alt` attribute contains several `<sub>` tags. This is invalid code and it causes `make4ht` DOM filters to fail.

One of DOM filters that are used by default, is `sectionid`, which changes links from the TOC to sections and uses human readable links instead of numerical IDs.

When you run TeX4ebook, it produces multiple HTML files. DOM filters fails only on the file that contain your Tikzcd image, but they are executed on the file that contain TOC. This results in TOC that contain human readable links, but the sections that are destinations of these links don't get updated.

Now to fix that, you have multiple possibilities. First is to disable DOM filter processing, using

```
tex4ebook -f epub-common_domfilters  filename.tex
```

This may cause other issues, as these filters cleans lot of issues in the HTML code.

Other possibility is to require pictures for inline math. I don't really understand why, but it doesn't produce these spurious `<sup>` tags. You can try it using

```
tex4ebook filename.tex "pic-m"
```

The downside is that all inline math will be turned into pictures.

If you don't mind to change your TeX file, I think the best thing to do is to use a custom environment for your `tikzcd`:

```
 \newenvironment{tikzcdmath}{$\begin{tikzcd}[cramped]}{\end{tikzcd}$}

...
There is a colimit
\begin{tikzcdmath}
\cat{X}_0\ar[r] & \cat{X}_1\ar[r] & \mc{X}_2\arrow[r] & \dots\ar[r] & \cat{X}.
\end{tikzcdmath}
```

And configure this environment in a `.cfg` file to use pictures:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ConfigureEnv{tikzcdmath}{\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

[image]

And link destinations are correct:

```html
<h3 class='sectionHead' id='something'><span class='titlemark'>1. </span> <a id='x3-20001'></a>Something</h3>
<!-- l. 30 --><p class='noindent'><span class='subsectionHead' id='else'><span class='titlemark'>1.1. </span> <a id='x3-30001.1'></a><span class='cmbx-10'>Else.</span></span>
```

Comment: It seems that one should not add `$` around `tikz-cd`, at least it is not the suggested way in the [document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf). Is there a version `pic-tikzcd` instead of the manual configuration `\ConfigureEnv{tikzcd}{\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture}{}{}`?

Comment: @Yai0Phah I think that this `\ConfigureEnv{tikzcd}` is actually nice solution in your case. If you put it into a `tikz-cd.4ht `, it will load automatically. I can also put that into TeX4ht sources, if it works well in all cases.